# Microsoft Kinect SDK Zoom/Scroll getsures

Tags: gestures, kinect-sdk

We are writing software to enable mouse control via kinect on Windows. Basic mouse functions are working well.

Now we want to add things like zoom and pan.

Now, these functions are not applicable to every application, and it might be that this is only possible on an application by application basis, or perhaps there is a way.

IN basic terms we would like to be able to use our kinect software to do pan and zoom in google maps/earth, and any app where there is a vertical/horizontal scrollbar.

We also like to implement rotate using two handed gesture as the rotation axis. Again this does not apply to all software.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am also doing a similar thing like you, how are you controlling the mouse using Kinect?